# Azure Pipelines secure file unique identifier

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

In Azure Pipelines you can upload a secure file.  Below I have uploaded a .p12 certificate file.

[image]

Then, you can reference this file with the InstallAppleCertificate@2 task.  How do you get the GUID value for the unique identifier of the file?  I am not seeing where I can find this value.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do you get the GUID value for the unique identifier of the file?

According to the reply for the [issue 8112](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/8112) on github:

> The id is **not displayed in the frontend** but if you open the
> `WebDeveloperTools` of a browser of your choice, go to
> `library`->`secureFiles` and open/reload the page there is a request named
> 'securefiles' that returns a json containing the list of securefiles
> and their ids.

As test, I enable the WebDeveloperTools by shortcut key `F12`, then open the page 'securefiles', I could get the GUID in the Response preview tab:

[image]

Besides, we could also use the file name instead of the GUID for the securefiles.

Answer (score 2):

When viewing the secure file in your browser if you expand the URL it has a query parameter "secureFileId" which is the GUID you're looking for.